# Ffmpeg : add logo and scrolling text in live ffpmeg feed

Tags: ffmpeg, obs-studio

We are using ffmpeg in nginx-rtmp server. And wanted to add logo and scrolling text on live streams.
Example video - https://youtu.be/ulzAyVZwxE8

These scrolls are applied with OBS studio. We want move this process to server side where we can send a plain feed to server and ffmpeg can apply text scrolling and logo on fly. Can we do this with ffmpeg or any other server side tool OBS studio cli mybe, if yes how?